# Replace only single letters and not letters which occur in pairs using PHP Regex

Tags: php, regex

This is the input string:

```
BQ^2*Z*(2*Y + Z) == AP^2*Y^2 - PQ^2*Y^2
```

This is the desired output:

```
BQ^2*$z*(2*$y + $z) == AP^2*$y^2 - PQ^2*$y^2
```

I tried using the following regex:

```
([A-Z])(?![A-Z])
```

However, it only leaves the first character out of the replacement. The current result is:

```
B$1^2*$1*(2*$1 + $1) == A$1^2*$1^2 - P$1^2*$1^2
```

How should I change the above regex to get the right output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use lookaround regex:

```
$repl = preg_replace('/(?<![A-Z])[A-Z](?![A-Z])/', '$$0', $str);
//=> BQ^2*$Z*(2*$Y + $Z) == AP^2*$Y^2 - PQ^2*$Y^2
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/O0ECYM/1)

**RegEx Explanation:**

- `(?<![A-Z])`: Lookbehind to assert that we don't have an uppercase letter at previous position
- `[A-Z]`: Match an uppercase letter
- `(?![A-Z])`: Lookahead to assert that we don't have an uppercase letter at next position

**Additional note:**

For your given input following regex will also work:

```
\b[A-Z]\b
```

But will miss matching `Y` in input: `PQ^2*5Y^2`

Comment: Thanks Anubhav. :) I forgot about the Lookbehind regex.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to lowercase your variable names, use preg_replace_callback:

```
$input = 'BQ^2*Z*(2*Y + Z) == AP^2*Y^2 - PQ^2*Y^2';

$output = preg_replace_callback(
            '/(?<![A-Z])[A-Z](?![A-Z])/',
            function ($m) {
                return '$' . strtolower($m[0]);
            },
            $input);
print_r($output);
```

**Output:**

```
BQ^2*$z*(2*$y + $z) == AP^2*$y^2 - PQ^2*$y^2
```